# OLEDBconnection exception: invalid argument in c#

Tags: c#, excel, oledbexception

It's my first try to to read test data for my automated test scripts from excel sheet using oledbconnection with Dapper. Whatever i do, i get invalid argument exception. I need to select the cell from column C based on the values in columns A and B. Here is the code:

```
class ExcelDataAccess
{
    public static string TestDataFileConnection()
    {
        var fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Path\TestData.xlsx"];
        var con = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'", fileName);
        return con;
    }

    public static UserData GetTestData(int TestCaseNumber, string Key)
    {
        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(TestDataFileConnection()))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var query = string.Format("select * from [DataSet$] where [TestCaseNumber]='{0}' and [Key]='{1}'", TestCaseNumber, Key);
            var value = connection.Query<UserData>(query).FirstOrDefault();
            connection.Close();
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

In the UserData class I get and set public variables with the table headers.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You may want to surround the filename value with quotes in your connection string: Data Source = '{0}'. In addition, it is not clear what this value evaluates to: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Path\TestData.xlsx"] It looks like you're using AppSettings collection incorrectly.

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: @uncoder  that's true regarding the quotes, but it didn't help. As for Path\TestData.xlsx , it's a path to the file in the system [@"C:\...\Scripts\TestData.xlsx"]

Comment: @Steve it complains on the line connection.Open();

Comment: You may want to clarify which line throws the exception then.

Comment: Please check with the debugger what file is used as Data Source in your connection string. It should be a valid full filename (complete with path) and it should be an XLSX file

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this line is the problem:

```
var fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Path\TestData.xlsx"];
```

Do you really have an entry in your app.config with a key of `Path\TestData.xlsx`?  Can you show that line of your app's .config file?

I think you may have used the wrong key.  Double check your entries in the `appSettings` section of your app's .config file.

Comment: You are right, thanks! I added a key but declared it incorrectly.